# How do I write test documentation for exception groups

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have a function that raises several, non-related exceptions using the Exception subclass ExceptionGroup, available only for python version 3.11. While the function works perfectly, writing the test documentation is proving impossible as the exception raised has "|" and "+" symbols to the left of the writing for indentation purposes. Here's the visual below.

```
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
x_divided                            
  |     raise ExceptionGroup("There were errors", errors)
  | ExceptionGroup: There were errors (3 sub-exceptions)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | TypeError: matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats
    +---------------- 2 ----------------
    | TypeError: Each row of the matrix must have the same size
    +---------------- 3 ----------------
    | ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
    +------------------------------------
```

While it may seem okay at face value, I can not recreate the same output for my test documentation as it would show a failed test.

For demonstration purposes, this is the test documentation I had for the specific function(S is the function):

```
"""
Test for more than one error
>>> s([[2, 4], [6, 6, "f"]], 0)
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
x_divided                            
  |     raise ExceptionGroup("There were errors", errors)
  | ExceptionGroup: There were errors (3 sub-exceptions)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | TypeError: matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats
    +---------------- 2 ----------------
    | TypeError: Each row of the matrix must have the same size
    +---------------- 3 ----------------
    | ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
    +------------------------------------
"""
```

On running doctest with a -v flag this is the output:

```
Failed example:
    s([[2, 4], [6, 6, "f"]], 0)
Exception raised:
      + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
      |   File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\doctest.py", line 1351, in __run
      |     exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      |   File "<doctest 2-matrix_divided.txt[5]>", line 1, in <module>
      |     s([[2, 4], [6, 6, "f"]], 0)
      |   File "C:\Users\pc\My Github code\alx-higher_level_programming\0x07-python-test_driven_development\2-matrix_divided.py", line 35, in matrix_divided
      |     raise ExceptionGroup("There were errors", errors)
      | ExceptionGroup: There were errors (3 sub-exceptions)
      +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
        | TypeError: matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats
        +---------------- 2 ----------------
        | TypeError: Each row of the matrix must have the same size
        +---------------- 3 ----------------
        | ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
        +------------------------------------
```

The exception raised is pretty much the same as that in my test documentation except for the traceback stack. This, as far as I know, should not be an issue as python ignores the writings in the traceback stack and only compares the raised error types. In fact, I could choose to omit the writings within the traceback stack using an ellipses(...) or just omit it entirely. Like in the example below, provided in the python documentations website:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValueError: detail
```

Instead of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ValueError: detail
```

How do I replicate this, especially since the "|" and "+" symbols make it harder to simply delete the unwanted Traceback stack. And why does copy pasting the output directly to the test documentation not not work? It usually does. Is this a bug in the current python version? It's making test documentation nearly impossible to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Doctest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/doctest.html) may not be the best tool. Normally one does not test the string version of an exception, it is very finicky and likely to change making for a fragile test. Instead you'd catch the exception and test the exception object. Also, if it's throwing "unrelated exceptions" that seems like a bug, or at least a trap for the user.

Comment: @Schwern What I meant by unrelated exceptions is that none of them depend on the other, and they can all be caught concurrently. My function divides all elements of a matrix by a divisor, which shouldn't be zero, and the size of the lists within the matrix should be the same size, and each element should be an integer or float. My exceptions check for these, and as you can see, all the errors can occur concurrently when calling the function. What should I use instead of doctest, and what do you mean by the string version of the exception? Thanks.

Comment: You're testing `ExceptionGroup.message`. Instead, use [`pytest.raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/reference.html#pytest-raises) to capture the ExceptionGroup *object* and then write asserts about its Exception *objects*. Also, there is a [backport of ExceptionGroup](https://pypi.org/project/exceptiongroup/) for older Pythons.

Answer (score 0):

To [test exceptions in a doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#what-about-exceptions)...

> The expected output for an exception must start with a traceback header, which may be either of the following two lines, indented the same as the first line of the example:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> Traceback (innermost last):
> ```

Your exception formatting will not work with that restriction.

You could perhaps make a feature request that doctests support ExceptionGroup. They're very new and it may have been an oversight.

---

For now, this may be better done as a normal unit test. Catch the ExceptionGroup and test it like any other object.

```
with raises(ExceptionGroup) as exception_group:
  s([[2, 4], [6, 6, "f"]], 0)

# This isn't a great test, just to demonstrate how to get at
# the individual exceptions.
assert exception_group.exceptions[0] is TypeError
assert exception_group.exceptions[1] is TypeError
assert exception_group.exceptions[2] is ZeroDivisionError
```

Comment: Got it. Let me try it out. Thanks.